# C++ CMake not referencing function with .h properly

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, cmake, reference, header

**SOLUTION:
Just don't be a noob and run `make` in the same directory as `cmake`
Thanks for your answers!**

I'm starting with C++ programming and I'm trying to understand how to properly reference a function with .h and .cpp file. I have following files:

```
    \\func.h
    #ifndef FUNC_H
    #define FUNC_H

    int charout(int a, char b);

    #endif
```

---

```
    \\func.cpp
    #include <iostream>
    #include "func.h"
    using namespace std;

    int charout(int a, char b)
    {
        cout << a;
        cout << b;
    return 0;
    }
```

---

```
\\main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "func.h"
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int a; char b;

    cout << "insert an integer " << endl;
    cin >> a;
    cout << "insert a letter " << endl;
    cin >> b;
    charout(a,b);
return 0;
}
```

I am compiling using CMake (with func.h in folder 'include') with following structure:

```
# Declare the version of the CMake API for forward-compatibility
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
# Declare the name of the CMake Project
project(manual)
# Add the directory to search for header files
include_directories(include)
# Define an executable target
add_executable(main func.cpp main.cpp)
```

When I try to make main.cpp I am receiving an error:

> make main g++     main.cpp   -o main /tmp/cctlsXUG.o: In function
>   `main': main.cpp:(.text+0x80): undefined reference to`charout(int,
>   char)' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status : recipe
>   for target 'main' failed make: *** [main] Error 1

Can you please take a look and let me know where am I doing a mistake?
I will appreciate your feedback. I'm really stuck with this. Cheers!

---

**UPDATE:**
OK I managed to compile it with  `g++ func.cpp main.cpp - o main`  when I was trying to compile the same code with gcc I got errors of sort `undefined reference to` `std::cout'`
I've found out that gcc does not give an access to std of C++. Can I somehow fix my CMake files to use g++ instead of gcc? The project I have to deliver is supposed to have a CMakeLists.txt included.
Finally the last question: why does CMake works fine with function declaration and main in the same file, but not when I split the function into header, cpp and main?

Comment: Looks like `func.cpp` is not being compiled. Maybe you need to do a `cmake .` in the build folder to regenerate the Makefile. I use `CMake` daily but don't use Makefiles so I am not sure if this is automatic.

Comment: I tried that as well, even trying to compile just func.cpp separately, but then I'm getting an undefined reference to 'main' error: > g++     func.cpp   -o func
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
<builtin>: recipe for target 'func' failed
make: *** [func] Error 1

Comment: `When I try to make main.cpp I am receiving an error:` - Which **exact command** you run for build the project (after `cmake`)? `make`, `make main` or `make main.cpp`? The last invocation has a little sence, because your project already has `main.cpp` file and it shouldn't be rebuild.

Comment: I first executed `cmake ..` in the build folder then go back to the folder with .cpp files and `make main`.

Comment: You should run `make` from the **same directory** where you run `cmake` before.

Comment: @Tsyvarev oh god, okay that works perfectly fine. I'm a horse. But thank you for your help!